# How to reserve tickets in an ordering system?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for advice or idea about this situation.  I have a Table session. Each session can have up to X guest.

```
SESSION
idSession
MaxGuest
```

I have another table TICKETS. When someone order X tickets for a SESSION I would like to make sure there is enough ticket available between the moment he ordered the tickets and the moment the system has recorded his order.

Example:

[image]

If I have many orders at the same time I may have this problem.

The only idea I see is to have a table to store current process order and check the qty available from the number of tickets already ordered and the number of ticket being ordered.

Does anyone has a better idea? I wonder if it's not too "heavy"? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ordering systems often allow you to add something to a basket, and then you have a certain amount of time (e.g. 15 minutes) before those items expire. You then need to check if there are enough items at basket time, and then as long as the basket is not expired at payment time, there will be enough tickets to fulfil that order.

Comment: @halfer He wants to check before the order, not after the order. Once the user has clicked on "Purchase," you can do whatever you want (e.g. 15 minute timer). Users hate when they click "Purchase" and they get a message that says: "Unfortunately, we have run out of units."

Comment: @Programming: I think that's the same as my suggestion, unless I've misunderstood you. There's generally two stages to obtaining tickets: reserve (which I called basket) and pay/purchase, and the check is best at the first stage.

Comment: @Programming: I think that's the same as my suggestion, unless I've misunderstood you. There's generally two stages to obtaining tickets: reserve (which I called basket) and pay/purchase, and the check is best at the first stage.

Comment: Nico, would you mind clarifying? Do you want suggestions concerning both stages or one in particular? My answer focused on the stage of pay and purchase. If you want a reserve stage, all you need is a 15 minute timer and then a redirect. Let me know what you think...

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for replying ! Right, I want to check before the order is completed. 

User can order up to X ticket at the same time. In the database I will generate one record for each ticket. Let's assume i have 100 tickets left and 10 people ordering 12 tickets at the same time.

The system will allow all users to order tickets as when the click on purchase there was 100 tickets left. But while the system will insert each ticket of each order at the same time, some of users won't have all the tickets ...

Comment: Reading comments i understand that I have no other choice than using a temp order table and block the tickets for 15 mn for example.

Then when people order ticket, the maximum quantity is the number of tickets left to sell - the tickets in the temp table...

Comment: Do I answer your question? If not, what can I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **AJAX** and **PHP** for this idea to work. Without AJAX, information could be retrieved from the server that is not recent. Orders can happen in seconds. I would do something like this:

**init.php**

```
if($watching){
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

You could set `$watching` to retrieve information from your db and check if items are still available.

**page.php**

```
<script>
    function isWatching() {
        $.get('init.php', function(data){
                if(data == 1) {
                    alert('You are watching a video');
                } else if(data == 0) {
                    alert('You are not watching a video');
                }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(isWatching, 1000);
</script>
```

**NOTE:** I would not recommend setting the interval to one second.

Comment: *I would not recommend setting the interval to one second.* Can you please add a suggestion? What is recommended, a shorter or longer time?

Comment: The faster your application, the more it has to work. I would recommend a longer time for the average website, like 10-15 seconds. I did one second as the interval because it's easy to understand and is generally the standard.

Comment: Thanks, I recommend you to add this in your answer.